# Unable to construct Context-free Grammar from Pushdown Automaton 

Tags: computer-science, automata

I have a problem in constructing a Context-free Grammar for the Language $$L = \{a^mb^n : m≠n,m>0,n>0\} .$$ Though I can able to construct a Pushdown Automata.

[image: pda]

I can construct a CFG, but it accepts both $m \neq n$ and $m=n$.
My CFG is:

> $S \to aS/Sb/aSb/aab/abb $.

I cannot able to consturct the CFG to accept for $m \neq n$ alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
S ::= aSb | A | B
A ::= a | Aa
B ::= b | Bb
```

Comment: This will accept if my input is 'a' but the condition is both m,n>0

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT it is trivial to modify Henning's answer to make both m,n > 0. Just add T ::= aSb as the first production rule (and always start at T, this will force us to have at least one a and b.